# Storing Multilingual/unicode characters(thai,hindi,philliphine) in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode, multilingual

I have a MySQL DB. I created a table with below definition which supports multiple languages (Hindi, Thai, etc.).

```
CREATE TABLE test_multi_lang
(
   language_name varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
)

INSERT INTO test_multi_lang
(language_name )
VALUES
('ตัวอย่าง')

INSERT INTO test_multi_lang
(language_name )
VALUES
('नमूना')
```

**But when I select the data. It is showing all the data as `??????`.**

```
SELECT * FROM test_multi_lang
```

**Sample Image**
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it "showing the data"? Are you in an IDE or database UI tool? A command line window? Something else? If whatever ultimately displays the data is not set up for UTF-8 you'll get garbage out even if the data is correctly stored in the DB.

Comment: Did you try SET NAMES utf8

Comment: Change your table character set to `utf8_*`

Comment: I am selecting the data using TOAD for mysql. how do i check if the data correctly set in table or not. @JimGarrison

Comment: @MoteRahul I tried your code on my machine, it is working correctly.

Comment: @user4035. can you send me a screen shot how it is showing. what tool you are using to run the query.

Comment: I am using Toad for MYSQL 7.3.1.290 version. when I executed through console everything looks good. but when i executes in TOAD, It is showing as ?????? @user4035.

Comment: @Chakradhar Check the settings for TOAD, if there is encoding.

Comment: @user4035. Yes, there is setting Editor->Character Encoding->UTF-8. I enabled that too. But no luck. The result is same.

Comment: @Chakradhar Sorry, no idea. I have never used this tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's not MySQL fault: the data is not being correctly output in your client program. Here is how it looks on my Linux Slackware machine. Native MySQL console:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test_multi_lang
(
   language_name varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> insert into test_multi_lang
(language_name )
values
('ตัวอย่าง');


mysql> SELECT * FROM test_multi_lang;
+--------------------------+
| language_name            |
+--------------------------+
| ตัวอย่าง                 |
+--------------------------+

mysql>  SET NAMES latin1;

mysql> SELECT * FROM test_multi_lang;
+---------------+
| language_name |
+---------------+
| ????????      |
+---------------+

mysql>  SET NAMES utf8;

mysql> SELECT * FROM test_multi_lang;
+--------------------------+
| language_name            |
+--------------------------+
| ตัวอย่าง                 |
+--------------------------+
```

You see: as soon as we used `SET NAMES latin1`, we got question marks. Try to connect to MySQL, using console application, and use `SET NAMES utf8`.

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the character set of the returned result **before** running the `SELECT` query:

`SET NAMES 'utf8'`

and

`SET character_set_results = 'utf8', 
character_set_client = 'utf8', 
character_set_connection = 'utf8', 
character_set_database = 'utf8', 
character_set_server = 'utf8'`